# Recentf buffer is not interactively

Tags: ido, recentf

windows 10, emacs 26.1

I use **ido** mode.

in my init.el

```
(require 'ido)
(require 'ido-vertical-mode)
(ido-use-virtual-buffers t)
(ido-mode 1)
(ido-vertical-mode 1)
(setq ido-vertical-define-keys 'C-n-and-C-p-only)
(require 'recentf)
(recentf-mode t)
(setq recentf-max-menu-items 25)
(global-set-key "\C-x\ \C-r" 'recentf-open-files)
```

And when I press `C-x C-r` it show buffer of recent files.
Something like this:
[image]

And after I press , e.g. **3** , Emacs open file `d:/Personal/SPRINTS/sprint_174.org`

Nice. It's work. But... it's very slow.
Has any more interactively and fast approach. I want to filter interactively (on fly) the names of recent files. 
I want to do this is **ido**  mode. Something like in `helm` mode. But I don't like `helm`.

Is it possible?

Comment: It seems Ido has recentf support with the option `ido-use-virtual-buffers`.

Comment: I set  (ido-use-virtual-buffers t) but it not help. Same result,

Comment: Not sure what were you expecting. After setting `ido-use-virtual-buffers` to `t`, you should be able to access the recentf list via `M-x ido-switch-buffer`. I don't use Ido, that's all I know.

Comment: M-x ido-switch-buffer - show list of buffers. But I need list of recent opened files.

Comment: I need to see all recent buffers when I restart Emacs. Is it possible?